# Confused With This Math Answer Using Double Type Variable

Tags: objective-c, iphone

This is really weird, hopefully a fresh pair of eyes can help me figure this out. I happen to be using this code in an iPhone App, but I believe it's using simple C code so not sure this makes a difference or not. I have the user input a number (in this case the num will be 2.2). I then divide that number by 0.2.

On my calculator I get the answer of 11.

However, using the following code I get the answer of 10:

```
NSString *userNameFour = txtUserName4.text; 
double numFour = [userNameFour intValue];

double t_psd = numFour/0.2;
```

so now when I print the variable `t_psd`, I get 10.000000. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intValue` converts your string to an int, not a double. You want `doubleValue` instead :)

Comment: ah! You all that have answered are brilliant! I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Funny, it turned out that the shorter the answer is the better O.o

Answer (score 4):

That `intValue` bit looks suspicious... my guess is that `numFour` ends up being 2.0 rather than 2.2. Are you sure you didn't mean [`doubleValue`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-doubleValue)?

Try this:

```
NSString *userNameFour = txtUserName4.text; 
double numFour = [userNameFour doubleValue];

double t_psd = numFour / 0.2;
```

(This is one issue I have with numeric parsers which just *stop* when they reach a character they don't expect. If you'd been using Java or .NET with `Integer.parseInt` or `int.Parse` the error would have been obvious - an exception would have been thrown saying that "2.2" isn't a text representation of an integer.)

Answer (score 3):

`[userNameFour intValue]` gives back `(int) 2`, which casts into `(double) 2.0` when you assign it to `numFour`.  And `2.0 / 0.2 = 10.0`.

You want to use `[userNameFour doubleValue]`.